# .htaccess file rewrite problem (allowing on specifc string)

Tags: .htaccess

I have written below code in htaccess

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_-]+).php$ http://www.domain.com/myfile.php?page=inc-$1.php [NC]

I don't want to rewrite index.php file. index.php file should open as it opens. and i also not using any sepecrator "dir/" in htaccess. Mainly how will i check for specific strings to allow ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add a rewrite condition for index.php before your RewriteRule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index\.php$
```

So it will not redirect index.php

Comment: thanks it is working now. But i m getting problem with only "/" redirecting without any page name should also redirect to index page. Thanks again. a bit more modification